# Why String concat(String) method is acting differently?

Tags: java, string, immutability, concatenation

I please check the code below.

I can understand that String s1 is not assigned and so even though concat(string) method is used it is giving the original output.

But also, in case of String s2 no variable is assigned but concatenation worked.

Can someone please explain?

```
package com.stringconcat.main;

public class StringConcat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String  s1 = "Hello";
        s1.concat(" World");
        System.out.println("String s1 output: " + s1);

        String s2 = "Hello" /*s1*/;
        System.out.println("String s2 output: " + s2.concat(" World"));
    }
}
```

The outputs are: 
String s1 output: Hello
String s2 output: Hello World

Comment: `System.out.println("String s2 output: " + s2.concat(" World"));` is basically `String temp1 = "String s2 output: "; String temp2 = s2.concat(" World "); System.out.println(temp1 + temp2);`.

Comment: Thanks man !! Sorry, my bad, I missed it !!

Comment: OK GUYS!!! MY BAD, MY MISTAKE !! I AM SORRY THAT I MISSED IT AND THANKS TO THOSE WONDERFUL PEOPLE WHO JUST CARED TO CLEAR CONFUSION AND HELP AS MUCH AS THEY CAN !

IF ANYONE IS ANNOYED I APOLOGIZE AGAIN. IF THAT DOESN'T HELP GO HELP YOURSELF!

Comment: @AbhiroopNandiRay remove this comment, seriously. you will get flagged and most probably removed from stackoverflow and besides this is rude... like super rude

Answer (score 2):

Because in the second case you are concatenating the *result* of `s2.concat(" World")` to `"String s2 output: "`, you are not ignoring it.

Comment: Thank you !!! Sorry I missed it !!

Comment: @AbhiroopNandiRay it's ok...

Answer (score 0):

Concat returns a new instance of String containing the concatenated strings. You just drop this concatenated version by not assigning it to a variable.

Comment: I already got the  answer from some good person. Thanks for whatever you wanted to say.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `s1` is `Hello` while `s2.concat(" World")` is another 
`string` object with concatenated string as `Hello World`. `concat#string` method always return new instance of `string` object with concatenated string to it.